# Setting spreadsheet title with Guzzle in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, guzzle, guzzle6

I am connected to my Google sheets, when I run a post request for https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create and set no properties, it creates a new spreadsheet.

I would love to add a title so I did this

```
$options = [
    'form_params' => [
        'properties' => [
            'title' => 'A new title'
        ]
    ]
];
$client->post('v4/spreadsheets', $options);
```

I am using Guzzle to make this call. As a response I'm getting `HTTP status code 400 (Bad Request)` when adding `title` to form params.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You really should be using Google's SDK for this since they already have support for one in PHP.

According to their docs, sheet properties are set in a [`Google_Service_Sheets_SpreadsheetProperties`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Sheets_SpreadsheetProperties.html) instance which takes the `title` property.

An [example](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/create) from their docs:

```
<?php
$spreadsheet = new Google_Service_Sheets_Spreadsheet([
    'properties' => [
        'title' => $title
    ]
]);
$spreadsheet = $service->spreadsheets->create($spreadsheet, [
    'fields' => 'spreadsheetId'
]);
printf("Spreadsheet ID: %s\n", $spreadsheet->spreadsheetId);
```

Comment: The challenge here is that I'm working with ReactPHP. I can set a guzzle client via `setHttpClient` however I would have to replace every `get` or `post` call with `getAsync` or `postAsync`.

How would I do this? This is why I'm currently not using the SDK.

Comment: I don't understand how ReactPHP prevents you from using the SDK, but if you insist on composing the entire HTTP request by  yourself you are going to have to dig through all of the docs to figure out exactly what the API expects. Clearly, this isn't it. Personally, I would just use the SDK and spare myself the headache.

Comment: It does not prevent me from using the SDK, I want to make asynchronous calls though. The SDK only makes synchronous calls.